# How to access element.dataset.keyname in javascript

Tags: javascript, if-statement, dom, dataset

I have this code. I am creating a drag and drop-based application. The class `.all-boxes` is a div element. I basically want my code go through every single element that has the class of `.all-boxes` and then check if it has a child or not. If it does have a child (from me dropping the child element), I would like it to console log the parent element after I have dropped a child element on it.

```
function testing() {

  const allBoxes = document.querySelectorAll(".all-boxes");
  for (const box of allBoxes) {
    if (box.children.length < 0) {
      const dataY = box.dataset.y;
      const dataX = box.dataset.x;

      const datas = document.querySelector(`[data-y="${dataY}"][data-x="${dataX}"]`)
      console.log(datas);
    }
  }
}

testing();
```

I was able to test a basic version (code below) without the loop and if statement, and it was working fine and would log me the results I wanted.

````
function testing() {
  const box = document.querySelector("#dropzone-box1");

  const dataY = box.dataset.y;
  const dataX = box.dataset.x;

  const datas = document.querySelector(`[data-y="${dataY}"][data-x="${dataX}"]`)
  console.log(datas);
}

testing();```
````

Comment: What is happening in your code? What's the error? At most I'd say wrap your `querySelectorAll` in `Array.from()` for safety, but technically that shouldn't be an issue. Your code looks fine otherwise.

Comment: maybe you have a typo? `box.children.length < 0`